# Is there a way to view a dynamic website built on java's play framework locally?

Tags: java, html, dynamic, localhost, mamp

I am trying to view a webpage that was built on java's play framework and right now the only way I can view is if I commit the changes to the html and css to bitbucket and wait to show up on the test site. I would have to do this even if I want to change the color of a word. Of course when I simply click the link it shows a bunch of java syntax and html stuff and this is a dynamic site so that won't work. I am using inspect element on google chrome to make small changes but if I wanted to remake the layout of the website, using inspect element is not going to be efficient anymore. I just want to change the css and html but the website is written in the play framework. I looked everywhere and I see mentions on MAMP and PHP and MySql but I don't read anything about running a website built with java locally. Do I need to download MAMP or some other technology or software so I can going with front end design easier and do this locally before I push larger changes onto bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [the PlayFramework installation guide](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Installing). Please be sure to use the documentation associated to the version you use in your project

Be sure to hava the right version of java in the Path. Get the type-safe activator, it is a tool that will manage the different state of your app. And run the commande `activator run` from inside your project directory.

There is no need for MAMP or PHP. If your app needs mysql then you'll need it

Comment: I am doing front end web development for a company so I didn't create the project in my directory. the type-safe activator will not work.

Comment: If i correctly understand, you want to develop front end file with backend dynamic data without having local play server. I don't think it can be possible. You always have to refer to a server to access dynamic data. Your server can be local if you deploy the play project on your station or distant but you'll have to push your updated file to the server

Comment: so I will need a play server anyway even though I did not develop the java files on my computer? I thought running activator run will only work if you built an application through type-safe activator on my computer.

Comment: I don't know much about activator. It may depends on how your Java is built. You can probably get closer to your client's team. But if you want to work on dynamic front pages, it is compulsory to have a working server. You need the server to build the page with dynamic data and serve it to your browser. The other solution is to work on static file without rendering.